# Como exibir a soma de um valor X aonde estiver com um mesmo nome com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Vamos supor que eu tenho a seguinte tabela no meu bando de dados:

```
id | nome | valor
1  |gabriel|20
2  |gabriel|20
3  |Paulo|30
4  |Paulo|20
```

Eu preciso imprimir na minha tela um resultado assim usando PHP:

```
gabriel = 40;
Paulo = 50;
```

EU já tentei isso mas o código é completamente falho, apenas da certo se eu tiver apenas um mesmo nome:

```
get_erros_funcionarios($pdo);

                    function get_erros_funcionarios($pdo) {
                        $soma_get_valor = [];
                        $get_erros = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `erros_separador` ORDER BY `separador`");
                        $get_erros->execute();

                        $query = $get_erros->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                        foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
                            $erro_separador = $value['separador'];
                            array_push($soma_get_valor,$value['valor']);        
                        }
                        $soma_valor = array_sum($soma_get_valor);
                        echo $erro_separador;
                        echo    "<tr>". "\r\n".
                                    "<td class='th-1'>".$erro_separador."</td>"."\r\n".
                                    "<td class='th-2'>".$soma_valor."</td>"."\r\n".
                                "</tr>";
                    }
```

Alguém tem uma sugestão de como posso fazer isso usando PHP?

Comment: Não entendo muito de PHP, mas em questão SQL seria basicamente adicionar a instrução GROUP BY..

 Exemplo:
´SELECT * FROM erros_separador
GROUP BY nome
ORDER BY separador`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso em sua query SQL, da seguinte forma:

```
select nome, sum(valor) from erros_separador GROUP BY nome ORDER BY nome
```

Assim você trará a soma de todos os valores com o mesmo nome.